# How to display custom image in notification using ionic 2

Tags: angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2

Problem is getting square blank image in notification.

I have installed Local Notifications plugin

```
ionic plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification
```

**I have tried**

1)
saved image in `platforms\android\res\drawable\sample.png`

Here is code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {LocalNotifications} from 'ionic-native';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    LocalNotifications.schedule({
      id: 1,
      title: 'Title here',
      text: 'Text <b>here aaa</b>',
      led: "FF0000",
      icon: "sample"
    });
  }
}
```

2)
saved image in `\www\img\sample.png`

Here is code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {LocalNotifications} from 'ionic-native';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    LocalNotifications.schedule({
      id: 1,
      title: 'Delay Notification',
      at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600),
      text: 'Text <b>here aaa</b>',
      led: "FF0000",
      icon: "file://android_asset/www/img/sample.png"
    });
  }
}
```